# How to keep apache camel context alive in thread main

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-artemis

I'm trying to make simple application that will listen one queue from artemis and then proceed messages and after that create new message in second queue.

I have created in method Main Camel context and added routing (it forwards messages to bean). And to test this routing and that this bean works correctly I'm sending
few messages to this queue - rigth after context started in main thread

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616", "admin", "admin");
    context.addComponent("cmp/q2", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));

    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            from("cmp/q2:cmp/q2").bean(DataRequestor.class, "doSmth(${body}, ${headers})");
        }
    });

    ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
    context.start();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        HashMap<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        headers.put("header1", "some header info");
        template.sendBodyAndHeaders("cmp/q2:cmp/q2", "Test Message: " + i, headers);
    }
    context.stop();
}
```

And in this case application works fine, but it stops when method main completed - it proceess only messages that were created by it self.
Now after I have test bean that is used in routing, I want to modify application such way that it should start and stay active(keeping camle context and routin alive ) - so that i can create massages manually in web UI (active mq management console).

But I really don't know how.
I have tried infinite loop with Thread.sleep(5000);
I tried to start one more thread(also with infinite loop) in main method. 
But it didn't work.(The most suspicious for me in case with infinite loop is that apllication is running, but when i create message in web UI it just desapears - and no any traces in system out that it was processed by my bean in routing, a suppose that it should be processed by my bean or just stay in the queue untouched, but it just disapears).

I now that my question is dummy, but I already have wasted 3 days to find a solution, so any advices or link to tutorials or some valueable information are appreciated.

PS: I've got one painfull restriction - Spring frameworks are not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most simple solution for running standalone camel is starting it with camel [Main](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/main/Main.html). Camel online documentation has also an example of using it http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html.
I will copy paste the example code here just in case:

```
public class MainExample {

    private Main main;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MainExample example = new MainExample();
        example.boot();
    }

    public void boot() throws Exception {
        // create a Main instance
        main = new Main();
        // bind MyBean into the registry
        main.bind("foo", new MyBean());
        // add routes
        main.addRouteBuilder(new MyRouteBuilder());
        // add event listener
        main.addMainListener(new Events());
        // set the properties from a file
        main.setPropertyPlaceholderLocations("example.properties");
        // run until you terminate the JVM
        System.out.println("Starting Camel. Use ctrl + c to terminate the JVM.\n");
        main.run();
    }

    private static class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("timer:foo?delay={{millisecs}}")
                .process(new Processor() {
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("Invoked timer at " + new Date());
                    }
                })
                .bean("foo");
        }
    }

    public static class MyBean {
        public void callMe() {
            System.out.println("MyBean.callMe method has been called");
        }
    }

    public static class Events extends MainListenerSupport {

        @Override
        public void afterStart(MainSupport main) {
            System.out.println("MainExample with Camel is now started!");
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeStop(MainSupport main) {
            System.out.println("MainExample with Camel is now being stopped!");
        }
    }
}
```

The route keeps executing until you hit Ctlr+c or stop it in some other way...
If you test this, notice that you need example.properties file in your classpath, with the property `millisecs`.

Comment: Thank you, Stefan!
I have tried this variant, and application is running, and I can see the queue created by application.
But on the other hand I still have a problem - all messages I creat using web console just disappear from the queue.
No any traces in log of my application, also as no messages in the queue.
Also I can see next information in the queue details
Total messages added - 7
Total messages delivered - 0
Total messages acked - 7  (I can suggest that acked means acknowledged)

I have tried both types of routing - anycast(queue) and multicast(topic) - result is just the same

Comment: One more detail - message created manually in the queue just disapears and no futher proccessing acomplished inspite of the routing,
But when I'm moving message from other queue - everything works as expected

Comment: I suggest that you add more logging to your application to find out what happens to the messages. Also make sure that while debugging, you have only one instance of the app running. Setting log level to DEBUG or even TRACE can help you to find out what's really happening to the messages.

Comment: I've got system out at the very beginnig of the bean's method that i'm using in rounting - no any calls of that method. Also I found out that there is one difference between messages created manually using web-UI and created by script - messages created via web-UI has no User Id. And only messages with user ID created by script go through routing. I have generated some messages in other queue using script - all of them have User Id, and then in web-UI I have moved them to the target queue - all of the, were processed by bean. I suppose that the root of the problem is in the missing User Id

Answer (score 0):

At the very minimum you need a main thread to kick off a thread to run the camel route and then check for when that thread is done. The simple java threading approach using the main loop to check .wait() and the end of the camel route thread to signal .notify() when it finishes (or shutdown) would get the job done.

From there you can look into an executor service or use a micro-container like Apache Karaf

PS. Props for going Spring-free!

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** this is written in Kotlin but it is somewhat trivial to port to java

**Disclaimer:** this is written for Apache-Camel 2.24.2

**Disclaimer:** I am also learning about Apache-Camel. The docs are a little heavy for me

I tried the `Main` route to set it up but it quickly got a little convoluted. I know that this is a java thread but I'm using kotlin ATM, I'll leave most of the types and imports available so it's easier for java devs.

### class Listener

The first I had to fight with was understanding the lifecycle of `Main`. It turns out that there is an interface you can implement to add in the implementations of such events. With such an implementation I can hook up any routines that have to be sure that `camel` has started (no guessing required).

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext
import org.apache.camel.main.MainListener
import org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport

typealias Action = () -> Unit

class Listener : MainListener {
    private var afterStart: Action? = null
    fun registerOnStart(action:Action) {
        afterStart = action
    }
    override fun configure(context: CamelContext) {}
    override fun afterStop(main: MainSupport?) {}
    override fun afterStart(main: MainSupport?) {
        println("started!")
        afterStarted?.invoke().also { println("Launched the registered function") }
                ?: println("Nothing registered to start")
    }
    override fun beforeStop(main: MainSupport?) {}
    override fun beforeStart(main: MainSupport?) {}
}
```

### class ApplicationCore

Then I set up the configuration of the `context` (**Routes**, **Components**, etc,...)

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext
import org.apache.camel.impl.SimpleRegistry
import org.apache.camel.main.Main

class ApplicationCore : Runnable {
    private val main = Main()
    private val registry = SimpleRegistry()
    private val context = DefaultCamelContext(registry)
    private val listener = Listener() // defined above

    // for Java devs: this is more or less a constructor block
    init {
        main.camelContexts.clear()
        listener.registerOnStart({ whateverYouAreDoing().start() })// <- your stuff should run in its own thread because main will be blocked
        main.camelContexts.add(context)
        main.duration = -1
        context.addComponent("artemis", ...)// <- you need to implement your own
        context.addRoutes(...)// <- you already know how to do this
        ...// <- anything else you could need to initialize
        main.addMainListener(listener)
    }

    fun run() {
        /* ... add whatever else you need ... */

        // The next line blocks the thread until you close it
        main.run()
    }

    fun whateverYouAreDoing(): Thread {
        return Thread() {
            ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
            for (i in 0..1) {
                val headers = HashMap<String, Any>()
                headers["header1"] = "some header info"
                template.sendBodyAndHeaders("cmp/q2:cmp/q2", "Test Message: $i", headers)
            }
            context.stop()// <- this is not good practice here but its what you seem to want
        }
    }
}
```

In **kotlin**, initialization is rather easy. You can easily translate this into java because it is quite straight forward

```
// top level declaration
fun main(vararg args:List<String>) = { ApplicationCore().run() }
```